# Создать ограничение по датам начало-конец, чтобы записи не имели пересечений

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Как можно создать ограничение на уровне РСУБД MySQL или Postgresql, чтобы записи одного и того же типа (`type`) не могли пересекаться по интервалу дат начало-конец?

Например, есть запись с типом `type = uri_1` и интервалом `publish_up .. publish_down` равным `2020-08-10 00:00:00 .. 2020-08-20 00:00:00`. Ограничение должно запрещать вставку записи с тем же типом и пересечением интервала, например это будет `2020-08-15 00:00:00 .. 2020-08-30 00:00:00`. Но аналогичная запись с `type = uri_2` вставляться должна.

Интересует решение для любой РСУБД: MySQL или Postgresql

Answer (score 1):

В postgresql можно воспользоваться [ограничениями-исключениями](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/ddl-constraints#ddl-constraints-exclusion) (exclusion constraints):

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

CREATE TABLE intervals (
type text,
publish_up timestamp,
publish_down timestamp,
EXCLUDE USING GIST (type WITH =, tsrange(publish_up, publish_down) WITH &&)
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Я мало знаком с Postgresql, просто знаю что там есть как раз такие возможности, поэтому написал сразу две эти РСУБД. А средствами MySql такое принципиально нельзя сделать?